# How can I disable automatic options statements in SAS University Edition?

Tags: sas

Whenever I submit code in SAS University Edition, statements like this are inserted automatically and show up in the log:

```
OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
```

What causes this, and is there a way to disable it? I'm not even sure whether these statements are doing anything, as all the associated content is still displayed in the log.

After following Dwal's suggestion below, here is all of the additional generated code:

```
 1          OPTIONS NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 2          TITLE;
 3          FOOTNOTE;
 4          OPTIONS LOCALE=en_US DFLANG=LOCALE;
 5          DATA _NULL_;
 6          VALUE=GETOPTION("VALIDVARNAME");
 7          CALL SYMPUT("_WEBVVN", VALUE);
 8          RUN;

 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.01 seconds


 9          OPTIONS VALIDVARNAME=V7;
 10         FILENAME _HTMLOUT TEMP;
 11         FILENAME _GSFNAME TEMP;
 12         FILENAME _DATAOUT TEMP;
 13         %LET SYSCC=0;
 14         %LET _CLIENTAPP=SAS Studio;
 15         %LET _CLIENTAPPVERSION=3.3;
 16         %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE = %BQUOTE();
 17         %LET _BASEURL = %BQUOTE(http://localhost:10080/SASStudio/);
 18         %LET _EXECENV=SASProgrammer;
 19         DATA _NULL_;
 20         CALL SYMPUT("GRAPHINIT","");
 21         CALL SYMPUT("GRAPHTERM","");
 22         RC=TSLVL('GEOCODE');
 23         _ERROR_=0;
 24         IF (RC^=' ') THEN DO;
 25         CALL SYMPUT("GRAPHINIT","GOPTIONS RESET=ALL GSFNAME=_GSFNAME;");
 26         CALL SYMPUT("GRAPHTERM","GOPTIONS NOACCESSIBLE;");
 27         END;
 28         RUN;

 NOTE: Argument 1 to function TSLVL('GEOCODE') at line 22 column 4 is invalid.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.01 seconds


 29         DATA _NULL_;
 30         RC=SYSPROD("PRODNUM002");
 31         IF (RC^=1) THEN DO;
 32         CALL SYMPUT("GRAPHINIT","");
 33         CALL SYMPUT("GRAPHTERM","");
 34         END;
 35         RUN;

 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.00 seconds


 36         %LET _DATAOUT_MIME_TYPE=;
 37         %LET _DATAOUT_NAME=;
 38         %LET _DATAOUT_TABLE=;
 39         %LET _DATAOUT_URL=;
 40         %SYMDEL _DATAOUT_MIME_TYPE _DATAOUT_NAME _DATAOUT_URL _DATAOUT_TABLE;
 41         %LET _SASWS_ = %BQUOTE(/folders/myfolders);
 42         %LET _SASWSTEMP_=%BQUOTE(/folders/myfolders/.images/c1930fcb-2ffb-4ae0-8bfe-624b39b851b9);
 43         ODS LISTING CLOSE;
 44         OPTIONS PRINTERPATH=PDF;
 45         ODS AUTONAVIGATE OFF;
 46         ODS GRAPHICS ON;
 47         ODS HTML5 (ID=WEB) DEVICE=PNG GPATH="&_SASWSTEMP_" ENCODING=utf8 FILE=_HTMLOUT (TITLE='Results: Program') STYLE=Htmlblue
 47       ! OPTIONS(BITMAP_MODE='INLINE' SVG_MODE='INLINE' CSS_PREFIX='.ods_c1930fcb-2ffb-4ae0-8bfe-624b39b851b9'
 47       ! BODY_ID='div_c1930fcb-2ffb-4ae0-8bfe-624b39b851b9' );
 NOTE: Writing HTML5(WEB) Body file: _HTMLOUT
 48         &GRAPHINIT;
 49         OPTIONS FIRSTOBS=1;
 50         OPTIONS OBS=MAX;
 51         OPTIONS DTRESET DATE NUMBER NOTES;
 52         OPTIONS NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 53
```

The bit I actually submitted:

```
 54         data _null_;
 55         put "Hello";
 56         run;

 Hello
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

And then some more afterwards:

```
 57         
 58         OPTIONS NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 59         ODS HTML CLOSE;
 60         &GRAPHTERM; ;*';*";*/;RUN;QUIT;
 61         QUIT;RUN;
 62         OPTIONS VALIDVARNAME=&_WEBVVN;
 63         %SYMDEL _WEBVVN;
 64         ODS HTML5 (ID=WEB) CLOSE;
 65         
 66         FILENAME _GSFNAME;
 NOTE: Fileref _GSFNAME has been deassigned.
 67         DATA _NULL_;RUN;

 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.00 seconds


 67       !                 OPTIONS NOTES STIMER SOURCE SYNTAXCHECK;
 68
```

Comment: I couldn't tell you what it's for or how to get rid of it. You'll also notice that there are a bunch of line numbers that are skipped before and after your code. If you went to 'preferences', and checked "show generated code in SAS log," it would print all this extra code to the log and might give you a better idea as to its purpose.

Comment: Thanks - updated. If you posted this as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There's several places that options can be set in SAS - the below list are in order of precedence (ie #1 supercedes #2 etc):

1. Restricted options table, if it exists (if you're on a university sever these may have been set)
2. OPTIONS statement (or SAS System Options window)
3. Autoexec file (that contains an OPTIONS statement)
4. Command-line specification
5. Configuration file specification
6. SAS system default settings.

You can check the actual values of these options by sumbitting the following which will output a list of all the system options and their current values:

```
proc options define ;
run ;
```

From what you're saying, it sounds like the log is still outputing notes/source lines yes? If your seeing `OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;` in your log then it's just a guess but it could be that the statement is coming from an autoexec file (#3) which is then being superceded by unitversity restricted options (#1).

You can check this from the output of the `proc options` statement above by looking for the value of the `AUTOEXEC` option as this will specify the path to the autoexec file being submitted (if there is one).

Comment: The extra options statements are being inserted every time code is submitted (sometimes at multiple points in the code) rather than just once when the session is started, so I don't think an autoexec is the source. The actual autoexec file appears to be empty.